# django-debug-toolbar installation causes: No such file or directory: '/var/www/static'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install django-debug toolbar.  Using django 1.6.5 and toolbar 1.3.2

I did the pip install and added this line to my settings file INSTALLED_APPS:

```
...
django_toolbar,
```

Also in settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: You need the `STATIC_ROOT` setting

Comment: make sure you run the synchronization first 'syncdb'

Comment: Unrelated note (related one below), but Django 1.6.x is no longer support. There have been security releases that do not exist for Django 1.6.x. It is well worth upgrading to Django 1.8, which is a long-term release; guaranteed security updates for at least three years.

Answer (score 6):

You should declare STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS in your setting file.
Your setting file will look like

STATIC_ROOT = ' '

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        ('assets', '/home/...../...../static'),
)

### where '/home/...../...../static' is path of your static directory.

Comment: Apparently django-toolbar wants there to be a directory at /var/www/static.  In my system there wasn't one, so I added it. I didn't need to add STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: That probably isn't a good solution. I'm guessing that may be a Django Debug Toolbar default (/var/www/html is often the default document root for web servers). It would be better to configure it properly. Good luck!